# WTSRegisterSessionNotification Does Not Work on Windows 7

Tags: winapi

WTSRegisterSessionNotification does not work on some of our customer's machines.  It works on all the machines here in house.

We are all running Windows 7 SP1 32-bit.

The application is *not* running as a Windows service.

I ensured that wtsapi32.dll exists (windows/system32) on the customer's machine.

Is there anything else peculiar about these machines that could cause WTSRegisterSessionNotification to fail?

Comment: `WTSRegisterSessionNotification` does work on Windows 7. You are going to need to explain more clearly the manner in which your code fails. A good starting point would be if you showed your code.

Comment: `WTSRegisterSessionNotification()` has a return value, are you checking it? If it returns FALSE, `GetLastError()` will then tell you why.

Comment: Yes, I have submitted a test build which checks the error value and logs it if the return value is FALSE.  I haven't received the log file yet because I don't have direct access to the customer box...

Comment: I don't understand why you won't show your code.

Comment: I've experienced vaguely similar issues when third-party software was causing out-of-date DLLs to be loaded - in our case the problem was on x64 machines and was due to an out of date version of winsta.dll being introduced.  I'm not sure how best to diagnose this sort of issue when you don't have direct access to the affected machines - perhaps you could use Process Explorer on your machine to work out what DLLs should be loaded, then write some diagnostic code to log the version of each of these DLLs that is actually loaded in your app's process space on the client's machine.

Comment: Apparently, the call to WTSRegisterSessionNotification is working.  The notifications however are not being intercepted by my application (or for some reason, Windows is not sending them).  Does anyone have idea why that could be happening?  All the Remote Desktop Services are started on the customer's box.

Comment: I did close a bunch of apps running, and my application starts receiving notifications again. I don't know what app is messing up with the notifications, also I don't know yet how to ensure use the proper version of the winsta.dll. Maybe one app is not calling next handlers of wndproc properly.